# Problem with constructor containing an interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

So I have this typescript class with an interface implemented in the constructor parameter:

```
    interface responseObject {
      a: string;
      b: boolean;
      c?: boolean; 
   }

   class x
   {
     a: string;
     b: boolean;
     c: boolean; 
     constructor(args: responseObject) {
       //check if non optional parameters are not supplied
       if(!args.a || !args.b) throw new Error("Error"); 
       //Trying to initialize class data member -> not working
       this.a = args.a;
       this.b = args.b;
     }
   }
```

Now I have **two** questions, my **first** one is how can I access the different parameters supplied inside args, for example how could I check if they are both supplied (something that looks like the thing I tried `!args.a` or `!args.b`) and my **second** question is how can I supply a default value for `c` if it is not supplied?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that.

```
constructor({ a, b, c = 'defaultValue' }) {
    //check if non optional parameters are not supplied
    if(!a || !b) throw new Error("Error"); 
}
```

Note that you have to explicitly throw the error, there is no short syntax for that.

Comment: Thank you for your response, however would that be possible using an interface and also declaring c as optional?

Comment: An interface has no JavaScript representation so it's unable to do runtime checking

Comment: Oh ok @Guerric P , and if I want c to be optional should I include `?` or not because there is already a default value?

Comment: ok, thank you! also last question, if I let's say want to access interface properties how would I do that, like is there something I could use like `args.a`?

Comment: You can use `arguments`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Comment: yeah waiting for the minute :D